# Data set for operating cost and revenue for small business?

Tags: data-request, finance, companies

I am messing with yelp academic data set right now and was wondering if there is any info on the financial situation for the small businesses?

Thanks

Edit: I am looking for the revenues of small businesses in New York, I am trying to analyze corresponding revenues change by the reviews of the customer on yelp.

For example: restaurant A has a 2011 revenue of y, during the end of 2011, a review z is on the yelp website, did that review cause 2012 revenue of A to increase or decrease.

In another word, I want to analyze the corresponding impact on the success each small business in new york due to the rating from yelp. I originally used the closure of a business to indicate the success of one business, but ultimately I would like to use revenue as the indicator, and I am missing that critical piece of data

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In [Infochimps](http://www.infochimps.com/tags/business), you will find hundreds of business related datasets. A few of them are from USA about tax return, receipts and net income. You will find also about revenues for certain business categories.

Visit here: [Website Link](http://www.infochimps.com/tags/business)

P.S. If you cannot find what you need in the link, please update your question with more details. Where you have already searched or/and an example of what exactly the dataset you want to contain.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, although I am aiming toward the revenues of small business in a specific area, for example I would like to know how much a pizza restaurant earned a year, and I want to correspond that to its review to see how the revenue is effected by the customer rating

Comment: This is way more specific than your initial question. Please add this example to your question as well. You will help other users to give you more proper answers :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :), I have added an update to my question